# Segfault with setting value to struct created using malloc

Tags: c, pointers, struct, segmentation-fault, malloc

I'm having a problem with my C code that I can't understand.
Here, I'm trying to create a struct pointer using malloc, but whenever I try to set values to the created struct, I run into a segmentation fault error. I used GDB to get as far as to where the errors were located, but I don't have much insight as how to fix it. If anyone could give me insight to this, I'd appreciate it.

This isn't the full code, but just the part that matters.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct str_s {
   int size;
   bool (*func)(const void* a, const void* b);
} *Str; // Cannot change this

Str create(bool (*func)(const void *a, const void *b)) {
  MapADT* str = malloc(sizeof(struct mapadt_s));
  (*str)->size = 0; // Segmentation Fault here
  (*str)->func= func;

  return *kv_map;
}
```

Comment: your type names are completely off. This code doesn't compile. Please create a [mcve] that works (and after that, you probably dereferencing a null/garbage pointer)

Comment: it should be `str->size = 0`. Thats assuming that mapadt_s is actually str_s. And test the return of malloc.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is a working version, the segfault come from the fact that you tried to deference your `str` pointer twice. Also, you have to return a pointer to the allocated memory not the value. Do no forget to free the allocated memory ;)

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct str_s {
   int size;
   bool (*func)(const void* a, const void* b);
} my_struct;

my_struct *create(bool (*func)(const void *a, const void *b)) {
  my_struct *str = malloc(sizeof(my_struct));
  str->size = 0;
  str->func = func;

  return str;
}
```

Comment: "types in C have no capital as first letter" - Please provide a reference to the standard disallowing this (or enforcing a specific naming scheme at all). That was also not stated by Jean-Francois. It is also not clear if that is the problem. We don't know which type `MapADT` is without a [mcve]. You just made up some speculative code.

Comment: No, you just speculate. OP does not provide enought information. Your code is not the same as OP provided. That's why we request a MCVE **before** answering. Please notice questions should be useful for future readers. We are not a debugging service. You might want to read [ask], too.